# Searching for any word or part of it inside string

Tags: postgresql, search, sql-like

I have been trying to implement search query, part of which is searching for a string. What I want to accomplish is search for any word(s) from an example string of ***"lorem ipsum dolor es"*** To claryfiy, I would like to find records which have *lorem* **OR** *lorem ipsum* **OR** dolor **OR** *lorem ipsum *dolor* es* if applicable.

What I tried so far:

> SIMILAR TO '%lorem ipsum dolor es%' - this obviously returns 0 since not a whole string is found
>
> LIKE LOWER '%lorem ipsum dolor es%' - same as above
>
> to_tsvector(files.desc) @@ 'lorem ipsum dolor es' - also empty result

Do I have to transform users input into and array of words to be able to accomplish my task?

EDIT:

My original idea was to be able to find occurrence of any part of the string in my table, which was solved by using below query. Yet I came across another obstacle. What if I want to search two tables by using one query and search strictly. If user types "lorem ipsum keyword4" I want it to find any image that has description containing any word of lorem ipsum AND that has keyword4 belonging to it. But I also want it to find images if one types "keyword4" or types "lorem ipsum". Below fiddle shows how it works in case one types "lorem ipsum keyword4". How do I do that?

[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/28bc0/4)

Comment: Your question does not make sense. If a string contains  `lorem ipsum dolor es`, the rest of your conditions is just noise. Please clarify.

Comment: As simple as searching for any word inside a string. If a user type "lorem ipsum dolor es", I want to be able to check if any of its words exist in my table, not necessarily the whole string, which @Nuri Tasdermir answered correctly

Comment: So your question should say **`OR`** where it says **`AND`** right now, and that would still be unclear, because you list arbitrary combinations. However, the accepted answer only finds matches where ***all*** words are contained in the same string, not just ***any*** of the words - which *neither* fits your question *nor* your comment. Please clarify your question with an *exact* definition. Also clarify if the search should be case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a function for search. Where p_name is a text input as 'lorem ipsum dolor es'. It finds patient records with name which includes all the words as a substring.

```
SELECT * FROM patient    
WHERE patient.name LIKE ALL (SELECT DISTINCT '%' || name || '%' FROM UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(p_name,' ')) AS name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and simplest way to find all strings that contain **any** of the **words** - treated as natural language words in the English language (default dictionary) in [Postgres text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch.html):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE  to_tsvector(string)
   @@  to_tsquery(replace('lorem ipsum dolor es'::text, ' ', '|'));
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d8d82/1)

Text search is case insensitive.
This can be supported with indexes very efficiently.